# Trailing whitespaces are being trimmed out from the JMS TextMessage (IBM MQ Message)

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I create a fixed-length text message which in some cases may contain trailing whitespace. For some reason these trailing spaces are being trimmed out. The message looks fine right before calling a `send` method on a `MessageProducer`, but in the IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer it's already truncated.

```
private function buildTextMessage(text: String, encoding: String): TextMessage {
  var message = _queueSession.createTextMessage()
  message.setText( encoding == null ? text : new String(text.getBytes(encoding)))
  return message
}
```

Above function is called with parameters as follows:
text - 2034 characters long String (message content)
encoding - String "UTF-8"

To create and send a message I use javax.jms-api-2.0 library for the MQ connection I use IBM client version 9.2.5.0.

Is there any MQ property I need to set to prevent this from happening?

I looked through all the properties for the `MQQueueConnectionFactory`, `QueueSender` (`MessageProducer`), and `Message` objects and the only thing I found interesting was compression so I set these properties:

```java
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setMsgCompList({WMQConstants.WMQ_COMPMSG_NONE})
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHdrCompList({WMQConstants.WMQ_COMPHDR_NONE})
```

But that didn't help either. Except these two and other connection related properties like channel, port, host, queue manager and the app name, I have also these:

```java
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType((WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT))
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTargetClientMatching(true)
```

for the QueueSender object I have these:

```java
sender.setTimeToLive(60000)
(sender.Destination as MQDestination).setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ)
```

And for the `Message` object I invoke only `setText` and `setJMSCorrelationID`.

For the moment I had to apply a workaround by adding a dummy character at the end of the message, and it works fine, but it just doesn't look nice.

Comment: Have you verified the message length? Does it include length of trailing spaces as well?

Comment: Can we please see your code where you put the message. Perhaps we'll notice something you have not seen.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Shashi message length includes trailing spaces.

Comment: If the message length includes trailing spaces, it may that MQExplorer has removed the trailing spaces. You can use the amqsbcg command to browse the message contents to verify the presence of trailing spaces.

Comment: I have just recreated it (putting a message containing trailing spaces with an MessageProducer - so much fun). Indeed, just for displaying the message in the "Message data" field the MQ Explorer trims the data. As you said, the "Data length" information is correct. Also a receiving application gets all characters including trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to see whether trailing blanks are really still there in the message when viewing it using MQ Explorer, here is a suggestion:

Open the "Message browser" from the right mouse click context menu on your queue.

[image]

You might find the "Data length" column reassuring here as it will contain a length that includes your spaces. However, continuing, double-click on the message you are worried about to bring up the "Message Properties" dialog. In this dialog, change to the "Data" section using the LHS navigation.

[image]

In here you will see a field entitled "Message data" which if you highlight will indeed show the trailing spaces from the string have been truncated for display purposes I suppose. This I believe is what your question is reporting.

However, since you are worried that the trailing spaces might actually have been truncated before the message got to the queue, you should make use of the next field down "Message data bytes" which will show you the trailing spaces are still present.